# CLI convert pptx to pdf WITHOUT libreoffice

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf, convert

I would like to convert sone pptx files to pdf, via the terminal. I know I can use

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf *.ppt
```

However, that requires me to install the whole ~400MB package of libreoffice applications (calc, writer, etc). Since I use onlyoffice, I don't need any libreoffice application. Is there a tool I can use to convert to pdf that DOESN'T need libreoffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

If OnlyOffice cannot do it from the command line, you will need to revert to another application that can understand the ppt format in order to convert it to PDF, and that provides a command line interface for the conversion.

Since it is not that obvious to fully support the ppt/pptx formats, the choice of applications will be limited.

I only can think of `libreoffice` and of `unoconv`. Installing `unoconv` equally will pull in most of Libreoffice, and use 352 MB of disk space. To convert ppt files only, installing `libreoffice-impress` will be enough and will require 265 MB.